# 2-step Google Authentication for Facebook?

Tags: facebook, security, authentication

I'm very confident for my account on Google, Dropbox, and Lastpass when they allow me to log in using two factors

1. the username+password
2. the [Google Authenticator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2)'s code generated from my smart phone.

I would love to have the same security protection for my Facebook account.

How can I get Google Authenticator code when signing in facebook.com?

Comment: This works perfectly.
http://andrew.kvalhe.im/how-to-set-up-google-authenticator-with-facebook/ Good Luck.

Comment: Link only answers aren't good answers. If the link dies the answer becomes useless. Please include the relevant parts of the link in the actual answer itself.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They support it as described [here](https://www.facebook.com/help/132694786861712)

I quote the solution as below. The 3rd one is the `code generator` similar to [Google Authenticator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.authenticator2).

Indeed we can use Google Authenticator to get this code ^^, as @Sathya has mentioned in [his answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/46765/3520).

> If you've turned on login approvals, there are 3 different ways you
>   can collect your login code:
>
> 1. We'll send you a text (SMS) message with a login code each time you
>      need one
> 2. You can get 10 codes to have when you need them
> 3. You can activate our **Code Generator** (if you have the Facebook app on your smartphone) or use another app that generates codes

Answer (score 2):

You can use Google Authenticator as well. The "set up another way.." option [from Security settings in Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=security&section=code_generator&view) generates a QR code which can be imported into Authenticator

[image]

Comment: Yeah absolutely right ^^

Answer (score 1):

Facebook offers this sort of thing already via text message.
https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=10150172618258920

Answer (score 0):

Facebook offers different two-factor authentication options. You can get a one-time password via SMS or use different 2FA applications such as Google Authenticator which generate OTPs. Just click Security and Login -> Use two-factor authentication -> Code Generator -> third party app. Use the QR code to add the token to your Google Authenticator app. There are also hardware tokens which can be used as an alternative to Google Authenticator - Protectimus Slim NFC. The token can be programmed with this QR code and will generate one-time passwords to provide an additional protection of your account. Facebook supports U2F USB and NFC tokens as well. You can choose the option which is the most suitable for you.